# Получение id элемента, по которому происходит клик

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Необходимо скрывать контекстное меню по клику ЛКМ, но НЕ в случае нажатии на checkbox (слайдер из ios'a).
Как получить айди элемента по которому я кликаю и засунуть его в сравнение if?
Буду премного благодарен за код.

```
        document.addEventListener("click", event => {
            if (event.button !== 2) {
                if (айди объекта по которому кликаю != "l7") {
                        menu.classList.remove("active");
                    }
                }
        });
```

[image: Контекстное меню]

Comment: `event.target.id` ?

Comment: Помогло, спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id инициатора события можно получить из объекта event.target

```js
function getId(event){
  alert(event.target.id);
}
```

```html
<button id="customId" onClick="getId(event)">GET ID</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id="l1" onClick="foo(this.id)">L1</button>
<button id="l2" onClick="foo(this.id)">L2</button>
<button id="l3" onClick="foo(this.id)">L3</button>
<button id="l4" onClick="foo(this.id)">L4</button>
<button id="l5" onClick="foo(this.id)">L5</button>
<button id="l6" onClick="foo(this.id)">L6</button>
<button id="l7" onClick="foo(this.id)">L7</button>
<button id="l8" onClick="foo(this.id)">L8</button>
    
<script>
  function foo(paramId) {
      alert(paramId);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="l1">L1</button>
<button class="btn" id="l2">L2</button>
<button class="btn" id="l3">L3</button>
<button class="btn" id="l4">L4</button>
<button class="btn" id="l5">L5</button>
<button class="btn" id="l6">L6</button>
<button class="btn" id="l7">L7</button>
<button class="btn" id="l8">L8</button>
```